# Stopping and optional times.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0},P)$ be a filtered probability space. Put $\mathcal{F}_{t^+}:=\cap_{s>t}\mathcal{F}_s$ and  $\{\mathcal{F}_{t^+}\}_{t\geq0}$ be the right-continuous filtration. A non-negative real random variable, $\tau$ is called a $\mathcal{F}_t$-stopping time iff $(\forall t\geq0)(\{\tau\leq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t)$ and a $\mathcal{F}_t$-optional time iff $(\forall t\geq0)(\{\tau<t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t)$

Show that $\tau$ is a $\mathcal{F}_{t^+}$-stopping time iff it is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-optional time.

I am having trouble showing the sufficient condition so this is what I've done so far, please correct any errors.

(Necessity) If $\tau$ is a $\mathcal{F}_{t^+}$-stopping time, then for a $t\geq0$  and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\{\tau\leq t-1/n\}\in\mathcal{F}_{t-1/n^+}\subset\mathcal{F}_t$, thus $\{\tau<t\}=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{\tau\leq t-1/n\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$

(Sufficiency) If $\tau$ is a $\mathcal{F}_{t}$-optional time, then for any $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq m$ $\{\tau<t+1/n\}\in\mathcal{F}_{t+1/m}\supset\mathcal{F}_{t^+}$, therefore, $\{\tau\leq t\}=\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{\tau< t+1/n\}\in\cap_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_t(\subset\mathcal{F}_{t^+})???$  The problem is of course with the last step so any suggestions of how I can get unstuck.

My second question relates to a claim made by the notes I am using that If $\tau$ is a $\mathcal{F}_{t^+}$-stopping time, then $\{\tau=t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$, and they say this is true as $\{\tau=t\}=\{\tau\leq t\}\setminus\{\tau<t\}$. I believe that is wrong and maybe there is a typing error and it should read that $\{\tau=t\}$ is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-stopping time. So is the claim correct or am I wrong.

Thanks in advance any help is really appreciated.

Comment: For the sufficiency, you may want to argue as follows: if $\tau$ is optional, then by definition, for any $t\geq 0$, $\{ \tau < t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$, then $$\{ \tau \leq t \} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \big( \tau \leq t + n^{-1} \big) \in \mathcal{F}_{t + m^{-1}}     \text{for any $m\geq 1$.}$$ Thus $$ \{ \tau \leq t \}  \in \bigcap_{m\geq 1}\mathcal{F}_{t + m^{-1}} =: \mathcal{F}_{t+}   $$**QED**